# Recommended way of loading config file from jenkins pipeline groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to load a config value (something like json, yaml, xml or ini) from a jenkins pipeline script. When I try to use `org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml` I get

> Scripts not permitted to use new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

I know I can unlock `org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yam`, but the message tells me that this does not seem to be the standard way of loading config files.

Is there a way of loading config files that is already unlocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html):

```
def config = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File("config.json"))
```

Comment: Need to write it like this: groovy,json.JsonSlurper (or import the module). thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the same error about JsonSlurper: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.json.JsonSlurper

Comment: @TudorCarean it's late, but to fix this you need to allow that method in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > In-Process Script Approvals then click on Approve

Answer (score 8):

If anyone looking for yaml parser in jenkinsfile, I recommend the following

```
 def yamlData = readYaml file: 'cae.yaml'
```

Reference : https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readyaml-code-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text

Comment: can you show this in the context of the Jenkinsfile ?  I was expecting to use an 'import' statement but that did not work.  is the def statement put inside or outside of the "pipeline" directive?